# How to keep track of AVL tree height without recursion?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

I'm trying to learn avl and bstrees, and I'm confused with how you're meant to store the height of a tree.

Usually I would use recursion every time I want the height of a tree, but then I don't think that'll be O(logn), if I'm using it with other funcs. So I was taught to keep a height var in the struct, but every time I want to update the height, I'll need to do recursion anyway unless I for example keep track of the parent node in the struct.

I was wondering if storing the parent inside the struct is what people usually do, and if so, how I would go about keeping track of the parent node? I'm still trying to learn, so I'm probably wrong about a lot of this...

`typedef struct Node { int data;  int height;  Tree left, right;  }`

Comment: Each node maintains how high up it is from the farthest leaf below it. Whenever you add or remove a node, the height may need to be adjusted as you pop out recursively to the parent.

Comment: If I remember it right, an AVL tree doesn't need to keep track of the absolute height. Keeping track of just the balance is enough.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Yes, that is true. I didn't sense the question was about how to maintain balance, however.

Comment: @jxh Oh I see, so if I'm understanding it correctly, rather than keeping track of the height from the root of the tree, I should keep track of the height from the lowest leaf of that node? I was looking to store the height of each node so I that could compare the left and right subtrees when, for example, going down a tree to insert a node, without the need of recursion to determine the heights of both subtrees.

Comment: @Rayden Each node can be considered the root of the sub-tree that is under it. But if you are just wondering about height balance, you only need a flag to indicate if one side is higher than the other.

Comment: @jxh ohhh ok, think I've got a better understanding of it now. Thank you so much for the help! I'll give it a shot!